# customize an error message in SQL server 2008 R2 on win 7

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, exception, windows-7

I need to customize an error message in SQL server 2008 R2 (no support for throw) on win 7.

```
  BEGIN TRY
   DECLARE @result INT
   SET @result = LOG(-1)
  END TRY

 BEGIN CATCH
  EXEC sys.sp_addmessage 60000, 16, 'log() argument is not positive'
  RAISERROR (60000, 16, 1)
 END CATCH
```

But, the result is always the same :

```
An invalid floating point operation occurred.
```

Thanks

Comment: This is a parse time error, so the -1 is being captured before the code is trying to be executed. You can bypass parsing by executing the stuff inside the try as dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can get around this by using a variable for the Log argument:

```
DECLARE @result INT
DECLARE @insidelog INT = -1
IF @insidelog < 0
    BEGIN
        EXEC sys.sp_addmessage 60000, 16, 'log() argument is not positive'
        RAISERROR (60000, 16, 1)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @result = LOG(@insidelog)
    END
```

I assume you'd be passing that number as a variable anyway.